# grouping values and creating a hashmap or list in java

Tags: java, list, loops, hashmap

sorry for asking another really obvious question

I have a following string :

```
{
 status=1,
 msg=1 out of 2 Transactions Fetched Successfully,
 transaction_details=
    {2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00, mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL},
     6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}
    }
}
```

and I want to group them in to a `HashMap` or to a `ArrayList` `really don't know what to use` if if give the transaction ids ex: `2298597 and 6503939` I should be able to get the other values like `status etc`.

I really don't know how to go about that is why ended up asking for help here.

Please help me with some inputs or if possible with sample code.

thanks

**EDIT**

I manage to put all values in to map and get values by keys now I am able to get values like the following :

```
transaction_details is the key
and Values : {2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00, mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}, 6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}}
```

now I have to group the values based the transactions numbers ex : `2298597` how do I go about ?

Comment: looks like you need a parser for your data format

Comment: Sounds like perfect use case for HashMap<String,WhateverStoragetype>

Comment: Is that JSON?  If so, you could put quotes around it and load it into an List of objects for further processing.

Comment: it's similar to json but it's not, so you could convert it to JSON and then use a library like gson.

Comment: Check my edit in a sec

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Transactions` class. Have all your variables and corresponding getters and setters. Override you `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` methods.

And as of what do choose between `HashMap` and `List` I would suggest go for HashMap as complexity for accessing data stored in HashMap is O(1). For List it is O(N)

Comment: +1 for your efforts, it would be nice if you could provide me with some sample

Answer (score 1):

As for me, you should create a datacontainer for your "string" (some sort of operation response right?) and put it into `Map` where keys would be your desired values (here some ids), and map's values would be just your datacontainer objects.

**EDIT:**

```
Map<String,MagicContainer> myMap=new HashMap<String,MagicContainer>();
MagicContainer message=new MagicContainer(message); // where message is lets say your example string
for(String singleId:message.getTransactionIDs()){
    myMap.put(singleId,message);
}

//now you can get your message by one of transactions id
String status=myMap.get("2298597").getStatus();
```

Ofc. it is up to you to write logic inside `MagicContainer` class (message parsing and getters + setters to important values)

EDIT:

In such case as you pointed in your edit, simply wrap map's values into list eg. `HashMap<String,List<MagicContainer>>()`, and while adding to map, check for existance of corresponding key, and if it exists, simply add your message to the list. Create new key with new list otherwise.

Comment: +1 for your efforts, it would be nice if you could provide me with some sample

Comment: Examples for map usage, or should I write datacontainer for you ??:)

Comment: Please have a look at my EDIT

Comment: I really fully don't understand `what this MagicContainer is `but try to understand it and do the things. thanks and really very kind of you .

Comment: MagicContainer is class that **YOU implement** (and call it whatever you like). Its responsibility is to parse transaction result message and provide easy to use methods for accessing important values.